# How do i fetch data from the backend to the frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql

I have this get API in my server side (Node JS):

```
app.get("/todos", async(req, res)=>{
    try {
        const allTodos = await pool.query("select * from todo;");
        res.json(allTodos.rows);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
    })
```

And of course it works when i tried it with Postman!
And here i have my ListTodo.js in my client side (React JS) in which i try to fetch data in it and display it in a table:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";


const ListTodo = () =>{

const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

const getTodos = async() => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/todos")
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        setTodos(jsonData)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
}

useEffect = (()=> {
    getTodos();
}, []);

console.log(todos);
return (
    <Fragment>
      <table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {todos.map(todo => (
    <tr>
        <td>{todo.description}</td>
        <td>Edit</td>
        <td>Delete</td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
</table>
    </Fragment>
 );
 }
export default ListTodo;
```

So if i try to console.log(jsonData) i get 2 empty arrays.

Comment: If you console.log allTodos   on Node after querying them, does it show your result properly?

Comment: What is the content of `allTodos.rows`?

Comment: { todo_id: '2', description: 'go to the super market!' },
  { todo_id: '3', description: 'play basketball!' },
  { todo_id: '4', description: 'i need to study' },
  { todo_id: '5', description: 'hello world!' },
  { todo_id: '6', description: 'go to class' }

Comment: Do you get any errors in the dev tools?

Comment: ahh wait when i put the code inside the useEffect it worked but when i call a function inside useEffect it tells me "useEffect is imported but never used" i don't get it

Comment: Hi, not an answer to your question as such, but you should handle errors in the backed differently. Right now, the server will never respond if the database query fails. I would suggest not catching the errors and use something like this library to handle async errors: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler

You could then make a general error-handling middleware that logs/reports errors in one place.

Comment: well ty bro, the thing is that im super new to react js and node js and im following some courses so most of that code isn't mine, im still not enough to handle errors probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
useEffect(()=> {
    getTodos();
}, []);
```

Instead of:

```
useEffect = (()=> {
    getTodos();
}, []);
```

You declared a new variable by accident

Comment: ahhhhhhh ffs xD the whole morning wasted, yes ty sir!

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me what's in the console

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(setTodos)
  .catch(console.error);
});
```

Comment: it consols nothing

Comment: can you try this url on fetch like this? I change my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is good but the problem is with something else, please show the output in your console.

Also, try replacing the 'http://localhost...' to 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users' and see if the fetch works.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you

Comment: 1. show us your console output.

Comment: 2. try replacing the url with what I sent, in order to see if it's the connection between client and server or something else

Comment: @ProgrammingHints

Comment: no bro ty, but the problem is solved i declared the useEffect in a wrong way